# How to center horizontal nav bar?

Tags: html, css, nav

How to center this thing ? I've tried couple ways but the nav. bar is not exactly in the middle of the site.

```
<style>

ul
{
background-color:red;
list-style-type:none;
}

li
{
float:left;
}

a
{
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
width:80px;
padding:20px;
text-align:center;
}

a:link
{
background-color:red;
}
a:hover
{
background-color:white;
}
</style>

<ul>

  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>

</ul>
```

Guys it works, the navbar is now centered correctly, but the text is not this time.

.......................

padding:0 to ul solves the problem.

thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove `float:left;` and add `display:inline-block;` to `li`.

Add `text-align: center;` `margin:0 auto;` and a `width` to `ul`.

Change to this:

```
ul {
    background-color:red;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:80%;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e2TUC/9/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you CSS as following:

```
ul {
    background-color:red;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:80%;
}
li { display: inline-block;}
a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:80px;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
a:link {background-color:red;}
a:hover { background-color:white;}
```

Notice 4 important lines added:

```
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:80%; - set the desirable width if not 100%
```

width can be also specified in absolute units, like e.g. `width:800px;` alternatively, 2nd and 3rd lines can be replaced with a single statement: `margin: 0 auto;`

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/e2TUC/**

Hope this will help. Regards,